# Cloning an internal HDD to external one through USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, clone

I need to clone an existing internal HDD; and I want to do this through a USB port on my laptop; is this feasible?

Comment: I would say that this is _possible_, but would take a very long time to do. For fastest results (excluding software), use 3.0 speed ports if your computer has one, and a SSD for the clone drive.

Answer (score 1):

Its absolutely possible.  Every disk cloning tool that I know of supports USB.  [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) are good choices.